# Sort Table inside ng-repeat on table header click

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have a table which is inside a ng-repeat. I want to sort the data from Ascending or descending order. I am a bit confused on order by. How can I possibly do that? My html code is as of the following:

```
<th>
    Product Name &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>

<tr ng-repeat=" item in items | orderBy:sort">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="checked"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ item.name }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<th>
    Product Name &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</th>

<tr ng-repeat=" item in items | orderBy : 'name'">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="checked"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ item.name }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its answering all of your question but i think it can help you understand how orderBy works.
I made demo that uses function and reverse when you click on the title.
If you need custom sort you can comment and i will try to edit this demo.
hope it helps :D.

```
 <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <a href="#" ng-click="swtichReverse()"> Product Name &nbsp;</a>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- you can use this example for value or function-->
    <!--  ng-repeat=" item in items | orderBy:'name':isSortReverse -->
    <tr ng-repeat=" item in items | orderBy:sort:isSortReverse">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="checked"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ item.name }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jB5MBX1GD2o65YiL2Qtp?p=preview

Comment: I am not able to make this work. My data is from a json file called by an API from the database.

Comment: The a href navigates to blank page when clicked

Comment: can you give me thr json example and how you want it to look? its too hars to guess what exactly you try to do